# JavaScript IE focus setTimeout not working with checkbox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus

I am trying to fix the known "JavaScript focus() does not work in IE" problem with the setTimeout workaround.  However, it is not working when it is being called from within a function called by a checkbox's onchange event handler.

In other words:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="TheCheckbox"
       onchange="theCheckboxChanged()" />Check Here

function theCheckboxChanged()
{
    setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("anotherElement").focus(); }
               , 100);
}
```

Yes, "anotherElement" exists at the time of the call - in fact, it works as written in Firefox.

It also does not work if the checkbox is formatted as:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="TheCheckbox"
       onchange="theCheckboxChanged()">Check Here</input>
```

Comment: if you set the doctype it **do** work in IE9, i've no access to previous version.

Comment: The code works for me in IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/rNwf5/3/ What type of element are you trying to focus?

Comment: @ssorallen, you need to run it in compat mode. There is a bug in compat mode which my answer below fixes.

Comment: Why would you develop for compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

A input element is an empty tag, it does not contain content. That is why

```
<input type="checkbox" id="TheCheckbox" onchange="theCheckboxChanged()">Check Here</input>
```

does not work.

You should be using a label

```
<input type="checkbox" id="TheCheckbox" onchange="theCheckboxChanged()"/><label for="TheCheckbox">Check Here</label>
```

Problem with quirks mode is [onchange is not triggered with click events](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-193-onchange-does-not-fire-properly.html). Change it to onclick and it will magically start to work.

Code is working fine focusing the element without a timeout. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RP3bk/1/)

Comment: have you really read the answer? the OP is asking why the code is not working, and it do not work in **quirk** mode... jsfiddle load the documents in html5 standard mode so it work with and without the timeout